# How can I translate Views overridden title?

Tags: 8, views

I have a dynamic view for different products and I use contextual filters to override the views title based on argument of the URL, Now if page translate that argument has same only language code is changed from the URL so that why page title not changed according to the current language, I want to translate the page title that I override with current language of the website

```
{{ arguments.type }}
```

I Override the title using argument type, any method to translate this let me know

Comment: You should be able to translate through the `Translate interface` page as any other interface string. First make sure you visit the page in another language so Drupal can pick it up into the translation db, then search for the string on the Translate interface page. That search is capitalization sensitive so be very mindful what you type, try shorter strings.

Comment: Using Translate Interface page it was already translated, but not able to on change on when page translated, I am using views override title feature under contextual filters

Comment: Maybe clear cache? Or you translated some other string that is similar?

Comment: You're right, I can't do it either, maybe it's a bug. These issues might be related: [Views contextual filter's title override is invisible to TitleResolver](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2787051), [View titles in breadcrumb and metatag title don't get properly translated](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2716019).